# Importing Tilemill produced mbtiles to CouchDB

Tags: tilemill, mapnik, mapproxy, couchdb

I'm using MapProxy to seed a CouchDB with tile images on a FreeBSD server.

My workflow is Tilemill -> mbtiles export -> mapproxy seed -> CouchDB.  For zoom levels 10 - 17, rendering takes ~ 2-3 days, but produces a quite small db file @ ~2mb.  I attribute this to the large spaces with no data and the use of link_single_color_images: true

In an effort to speed the rendering process up, I have tried rendering with mapnik.xml as my source instead of the mbtiles produced by Tilemill.  All good with a tremendous speed up, but at the cost of a database that is 20x larger due to MapProxy producing a tile for every z/x/y.  Most of the thousands of tiles produced are transparent with no data.

Aka link_single_color_images: true does not seem to be working with Mapnik source, but does with mbtiles as a source.

Is there a way to use link_single_color_image with Mapnik?

Comment: Mbtiles would have already created the aliases to a single tile.  I'm suspecting that link single color image is not configured or working correctly for either case.

Answer (score 1):

So completely changed my workflow and I have compact couchdb databases in a matter of seconds/minutes from mbtiles.  Reduced Tilemill -> Couchdb rendering by days.

New workflow:
Tilemill -> mbtiles -> cdbtiles -> couchdb

Using more of the great open-source software by MapBox et al (https://github.com/mapbox and mapbox.com)

Couple of gotchs to installing cdbtiles, at least for my PCBSD/FreeBSD 10.0 system.
See: https://www.npmjs.org/package/cdbtiles or the github

npm install cdbtiles doesn't work, use git clone as below.  Had to make ln -s python2 python for mbtiles install or fix the python env

Install - FreeBSD 10.0:

1. install node
2. install npm (separate in FreeBSD ports)
3. setenv CXX clang++
4. setenv CC clang
5. install devel/gmake
6. npm install tilelive -g
7. git clone https://github.com/mapbox/node-mbtiles.git
8. cd to node-mbtiles dir
9. npm install -g (gave me some grief, just fix errors - see above)
10. git clone https://github.com/vsivsi/cdbtiles.git
11. cd to cdbtiles dir
12. npm install -g

see: https://www.npmjs.org/package/cdbtiles

Use cmd:
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tilelive/bin/copy -s pyramid --minzoom=10 --maxzoom=18  "mbtiles:///Users/user/maps/Columbus.mbtiles" "cdbtiles://127.0.0.1:5984/columbus_tiles/"

Obviously sorted for your parameters and system.

Yields CouchDB of tiles same size as mbtiles imput file after compaction.

Access tiles from ol3:

```
my_tiles_couchdbLayerXYZ = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({url: "http://127.0.0.1:5984/xxxxx_cdbtiles
        /tile_{z}_{x}_{y}/tile"
    })
});
```